# JSONSchema not catching incorrect additional fields?

Tags: json, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

Using [this schema](https://pastebin.com/raw/0TP4uZxB), [this file](https://pastebin.com/raw/x22L2unj) does not catch the `name_en` and `legalName_en` fields under `parties/identifier`, even though `additionalProperties: false` is specified on the `identifier` property.

This is with:

```
 jsonschema schema.json -i file.json
```

on OSX, using [python-jsonschema](https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema).

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Comment: both links point to the json data

Comment: Sorry! Fixed link.

Comment: Why the close vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a bug - at least if it is it's also a bug in the processor which http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ uses.

What is weird is that there are other instances where `additionalProperties:false` has been specified where the validator is honouring it. There are four properties in the packageInfo section which are being caught eg:

> Property 'documentation_en' has not been defined and the schema does
>   not allow additional properties. Schema path:
>   http://standard.open-contracting.org/schema/1__1__0/release-schema.json#/properties/packageInfo/properties/publisher/additionalProperties

If I remove the excess properties from the packageInfo section then the entire payload validates fine.

I then removed the `patternProperties` property from the `Identity` definition and the validator started working. So something about the presence or value of patternProperties in a definition is preventing additionalProperties validation from working, is all I can surmise.

Furthermore, it's not just the existence of patternProperties which acts as the switch. I added a patternProperties property to the packageInfo definition to see if it stopped the validator from validating the 4 excess properties, but it still worked. So it must be something else. Very mysterious.

Comment: Thanks, that's super helpful. For my purposes I can just get rid of the `patternProperties` properties throughout. I wonder if it's the content of `patternProperties` which the validator doesn't like.